# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to make this script in python that downloads audio for the moment from youtube.

but I'm running into this issue and I don't figure out

```
def __downloader(self, link, save_path = "", save_name = "", extension = "mp3"):
        
        yt = YouTube(link) 
        yt_streams = yt.streams.filter(adaptive=True, only_audio=True, 
        file_extension=extension).order_by('resolution').desc().first()
        yt_streams.download(output_path = save_path, filename = save_name)

        return
```

this is the error

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'**

Comment: pretty self-explanatory to me. It looks like the result assigned to `yt_streams` is None.

Comment: I don't know this API but what jumps out is that there is no error path in your code. What if the resource is not found? That's what it seems like to me. Whatever you asked for isn't there so None was returned.